# Installing Same Components Under Delphi 2009 and Delphi XE not working

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009, delphi-xe

I have a set of custom components that I've been using in D2009. I have installed Delphi XE, and I'd like to be able to use these components in both IDE's while I'm upgrading my projects.  But when I install them in XE, they are no longer really usable in D2009.  A project will still compile, but the components no longer show up in the Tool Palette, and they don't appear in the form designer either.

No matter how I try to uninstall/reinstall, etc., I can't get the components to work in D2009.  I've verified that both IDE's have the component's directory in their library path.

What do I need to do here to get the components working in both IDE's?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The different versions of Delphi produce different sets of packages (*.bpl files) in different paths ("package output directory"). The design packages have to be loaded at runtime by the IDE. Now the Windows search path probably comes into play; when D2009 wants to load package x.bpl it resolves to the (incompatible) XE version of it because XE's package output directory is in the system search path before D2009's - this happens if you installed D2009 first and XE later (recommended).

The solution is to always use Library Suffix for your packages. I suggest you go by Delphi's own convention and use 120 for D2009 packages and 150 for XE packages. Your x.bpl becomes x120.bpl for D2009 and x150.bpl for XE.

Comment: Indeed. I usually have separate directories for the different package files (.dpk, .dproj etc.) for each version, and one common directory for the component files.