# Can't load CRDE2001.DLL

Tags: delphi

I have a small project (one form) written in Delphi 2007. I've completed a project a few
days ago and today I was tryin' to open a form, but instead of a form in a design
view this message was submitted:

Error creating form: Can't load CRDE2001.DLL. Make sure its located in the application's searchpath..

I have this CRDE2001.DLL in a folder, wich is referenced in a Search path in 
Project Options -> Directories/Conditionals. I can't figure out what's wrong,
why I can't see a form in a design view.

Please help,
Jani

Comment: A quick search reveals that this dll has something to do with Skyline Tools ImageLib Corporate Suite http://skylinetools.com/imagelib/corp/frame_d5.html Do you use these components? Maybe you have to reinstall them, because they got corrupted?

Comment: DLL libraries required by components at design time should IMHO be stored in location reachable by IDE itself, not just by the project. Copying of your `CRDE2001.DLL` to a common [`DLL search path`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586(v=vs.85).aspx) or simply to the `..\yourdelphipath\bin` path where the IDE executable is stored should resolve your problem (at least, if I remember that right when using `DScintilla` wrapper).

Comment: Don't copy any dll to the delphi bin directory in XE2+, since that will prevent you to start Delphi.

Comment: @JanezGorše get SysInternals ProcessMonitor - when troubles like that you just watch where the program (like Delphi or your app)tried to find and open that file or DLL - and that usually hints you what it wrong.

Comment: @Arioch you're right, in XE3+

Comment: Theoretically might be enough to copy that DLL library to the `*.bpl` library folder. They're by default stored in `c:\Users\Public\Documents\..yourdelphi..\Bpl`.

Comment: @TLama or any other fodler in %PATH% or in windows search order. While ago i had a habit to put custom dlls in \winnt\system - there are very few DLLs and i could easily see find them by eyes later :-)

Comment: @Arioch'The That's the wrong tool. The right tool is Dependency Walker in Profile mode.

Comment: @David can't discuss it, i never saw it more useful than CFF Explorer or Total Commander, but perhaps i miss something. Oooh, i used to think that Dep.Walker is part of WinSDK or MS VC++ SDK, but there seems to be a separate project wit hthe same name. Perhaps i'll have a look though actually i don't think it would add much to my toolbox. For exampel it is limited with DLLs while ProcessMonitor can help with any file including configurationc, DCUs, DCPs, etc. For 90% tasksit would not be worse than DependancyWalker.com but will give a benefit of being familiar  :-)

Comment: Similar questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3537414/how-to-install-classes-or-units-like-components-in-delphi-2007 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6747574/installing-same-components-under-delphi-2009-and-delphi-xe-not-working

Comment: and this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11894418/delphi-xe-not-finding-a-bpl